# Rail создание объекта has_many - belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть две модели `Task` и `Project` имеющие связь `has_many` - `belongs_to`.

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :project
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :tasks
end
```

Список все `Tasks` выводится как отдельная страница + для каждого `Project` выводится свой список `Tasks`. Следовательно создание и удаление task будет происходить немного по разному. Отсюда вопрос:

Как правильно составить условие для метода create, таким образом, что бы `Task` мог создаваться как самостоятельный объект, так и связанный с `Project`?

Знаний хватило только на написание 2х отдельных методов

## Для создания связанных объектов

```
def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @task = @project.tasks.create(task_params)
    redirect_to project_path(@project)

  end
```

## Для создания самостоятельного объекта

```
def create
    @task = current_user.tasks.new(task_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save
        format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
        format.js {}
        format.json { render json: @task, status: :created, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Как связать в один метод к сожалению не знаю

Comment: Можно. А можно не делать, можно выполнить их "два-в-одном". В чём, собстна, вопрос?

Comment: @D-side я исправил вопрос и уточнил вопрос

Comment: Два отдельных метода это очень даже ничего. Два существенно разных сценария использования и разные проверки доступа, теоретически.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решается добавлением во второй вариант метода, этой строчки кода

```
@task.project_id = params[:project_id]
```